# jquery delete image file in folder without using php or ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Who know that JQuery code can do unlink code like PHP without using AJAX or php file? For example, I want to delete or unlink aaa.jpg file from folder

```
www.myproject.com/images/aaa.jpg
```

when I click delete button.

Comment: you cant, js is client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete files that are stored on the server. There is a method called `delete` like post or get but it is just an information for the sever.

The only files you can delete with jquery or JavaScript are local files generated with the file api.